# Why does Google Finance display the wrong price for IOC (Indian Oil Corporation) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am using Google Sheets for fetching EOD prices of Indian stocks, using the function

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("IOC","price")
```

Google is returning 19.51 but the closing price for IOC on 11-11-2019 is INR 135.40.

Answer (score 3):

1. `price` shows real-time of a particular stock. To get closing price use `close`.
2. Use complete ticker symbol from [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=fin&sxsrf=ACYBGNRf5X4qJ8DEDIdd1yMa_ujFxGTJQA:1577000951322&q=NSE:%20IOC&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecRozi3w8sc9YSm9SWtOXmPU4OIKzsgvd80rySypFJLiYoOyBKT4uHj00_UNM5LKCsrMCnN5FrFy-AW7Wil4-jsDAKLW5EdHAAAA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnoous4sjmAhVpzTgGHX1GDiIQlq4CCEUwAQ&biw=1440&bih=821&dpr=2#scso=_-h__XfK3JpKG4-EP98yG2Ak7:0). "NSE:IOC" for Indian Oil.

For example:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:IOC","close",DATE(2019,11,11))
```

For more information you can visit the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en).

See this image as a working example: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
=ROUND(IF(MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"marketcap")/GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"shares"),GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price"))=0,GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"marketcap")/GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"shares"),MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"marketcap")/GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"shares"),GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price"))),3)
```

Haven't fully tested it yet but works so far.

Answer (score 0):

First of All Google Finance function is not designed to be used for only Indian Markets hence this problem is occuring. When you search for the live prices of IOC (Indian Oil Corporation as is yours case) its showing the prices of a scrip named IOC (Itochu Corp a Japanese Company listed on Frankfurt Stock exchange)[Price of IOC as FRA stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF3fH.png)

*So to Get the Price of Indian Oil Corporation you have to use the script name as **NSE:IOC** instead of just IOC*